# Someone Who Makes Hourglasses

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an English word for a person who makes hourglasses? Someone who works with gold is called a "goldsmith" and silver, "silversmith." A person who makes glass is called a "glassblower/maker" while a person who installs glass panes is called a "glazier." I figure there probably is one for a maker of hourglasses, but I just can't seem to find it... unless it's just simply, "hourglass maker."

Comment: ...not really sure if master glassblowers specialize only in hourglasses.

Comment: A *horologist* is a clock-maker (or someone who studies clock-making).  That could cover hourglasses as well.

Answer (score -2):

If you google “How are hour glasses made”, you will get straight to the answer to your own question.  That is what you should  do before posting a question.

http://www.madehow.com/Volume-5/Hourglass.html

The answer is equally obvious.  It needs a glass blower to blow two glass containers, put sand in one and then fuse them together.

I am only responding here because the article from ‘made how’ gives a fascinating account of the history of time devices, including the hour glass and its manufacture.

It is obvious that an hour glass requires the art of the glass blower.  I addition is needed a very accurate knowledge of the amount of sand required, as well as the thickness of aperture to allow the right rate of flow for the time required. But surely no glass blower would confine her/himself to hour glasses.  So a special term is not needed.